# UIScrollView, UIImageView and server requests

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Is it possible to request images from a server, put them into an Array of images and display them with PhotoScroller ? I downloaded the sample code from the apple development web site and dived into code. But i didn't find the place where to put our images instead of the sample images, and more, to get images from a server and not from the phone.
Thanks for any help or pointers on this question :).

Comment: Yes it is possible what have you tried?

Comment: i made a tutorial on ImageView, and managed to do a grid of images, but not to download images from a server, and far from doing a scroll image view like in the iphone, so i made researches and find PhotoScroller https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html , but it still little bit too hard for me to understand rough code like that. So maybe there are different ways to do it, or maybe someone already did some PhotoScroll ?

Comment: I was asking what have you tried code wise but by the sounds of it you have tried anything.

Comment: As i said i have the code i can show it, were i managed to display a grid of images, and on click they become full size. The problem is that i didn't find anything, except PhotoScroller to match what i want to do, but i doesn't understand anything. The code is too complicated. Secondly for the question about server to iphone image transfert i manage to make http request and build my database, but as soon as i have done my request i don't know/find how to store my image. i can edit my code here, no problem, i never come to stackoverflow without code, or at least 6/7 hours of researching.

Comment: Sorry voting to close as **Demonstrates a minimal understanding.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `UIImageView` category extension `UIImageView+AFNetworking` to easily display images from a URL in a `UIImageView`. The library is available [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

Comment: Thanks you, i will dig in that direction :).